# How to select distinct column once and blank to its similar id column

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want result like

```
Dept   Name     EmployeeCount   
IT     Ankit      4
       Aman       4
       Rakesh     4
       Rohhit     4
HR     Deepak     3
       Manoj      3
       Raj        3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use window function here -

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Dept = LAG(Dept) OVER() THEN NULL ELSE Dept END Dept
      ,Name
      ,COUNT(Name) OVER() EmployeeCount
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Comment: but how we can get count of name department wise?